# swipe detection and handling in WebKitGtk 1.6

Tags: javascript, c, web, webkit, gtk

Im building a simple embedded web browser using webkitgtk on Linux. What are some methods to detect swipes for page scrolling etc? Can I simply generate the required X11/gtk/gdk events and use javascript? If so what events do i need to simulate? Is there a more webkit native way  to do this?